# Looking to block the menu from showing for an AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

I am trying to block my AppCompatActivity's menu from being shown when the user presses the ActionBar Overflow button.  Looking at the documentation for the AppCompatActivity's onMenuOpened function, it states "The default implementation returns true.".

Since the Window.Callback implementation as well as the AppCompatDialog and Dialog's implementation all state that you can "Return true to allow the menu to open, or false to prevent the menu from opening.", I had hoped that returning false from my AppCompatActivity's onMenuOpened function would also prevent the menu from showing, but it did not work.

Is there a way to block the menu from showing for an AppCompatActivity?

Thank you,

Bob

Comment: Why do you have a menu, if you do not want the user using it? What is the broader scenario here?

Comment: The user could accidentally hit the menu button during active play.  I only want to display the menu if play isn't active.  If play is active I want to play an error tone to alert the user that the operation isn't allowed.  I'm able to block button selections that occur for buttons in the ActionBar.  I'd just like to block the menu as well.