# androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity#closeOptionsMenu doesn't close the menu

Tags: android, android-menu, android-11

I'm using a click on the menu to open a bottom sheet.

When this was initially implemented just returning `false` from `AppCompatActivity#onMenuOpened` didn't do the job.

I see that someone already [complained about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231362/looking-to-block-the-menu-from-showing-for-an-appcompatactivity) 5 years ago.

So I added a call to `AppCompatActivity#closeOptionsMenu` and it worked.

I updated my app to support API level 30 and now I noticed that it doesn't work. (Not sure if this is related to API 30, or if it broke earlier and I didn't notice)

This is the current code of `AppCompatActivity#closeOptionsMenu`

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (getWindow().hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL)
                && (actionBar == null || !actionBar.closeOptionsMenu())) {
            super.closeOptionsMenu();
        }
```

and the result of `actionBar.closeOptionsMenu()` is `true` - i.e. `super.closeOptionsMenu()` isn't called.
So I thought I would call the code in `android.app.Activity#closeOptionsMenu` directly

```
    public void closeOptionsMenu() {
        if (mWindow.hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) &&
                (mActionBar == null || !mActionBar.closeOptionsMenu())) {
            mWindow.closePanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL);
        }
    }
```

but this call `mWindow.closePanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL);` still didn't change things and the menu is still opened.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `closeOptionsMenu` inside `onMenuOpened` - I posted the close method to be called after `onMenuOpened`.

```
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        // Make sure the menu won't open
        new Handler().post(this::closeOptionsMenu);

        openBottomSheetMenu();
        return false;
    }
```

And this solved the specific issue I had - I still see the menu for a sec, but then it's closed.
I assume that it's wrong to call `close` while `open` is still running.

Still no sure why returning `false` didn't work